Proper way to open/close child window in Win32 API using C
I'm trying to learn Win32 API using C. At this point I can display a window, some controls, menus and handle some messages.Currently I'm working on a small application that has a main window and a settings window. I manage to create the main window and the settings window. The problem is that I don't know what is the best way to link them.
Below is the code of my first try:
LRESULT CALLBACK SettingsProc(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam)
{
 
  switch (Message){
    
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
      DestroyWindow(Window);
    } break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  
  return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam); 
} 

void CreateSettings(HWND Window)
{
  HINSTANCE Instance =  GetModuleHandle(NULL);

  WNDCLASSEX WindowClass = {};
  WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = SettingsProc;
  WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
  WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
  WindowClass.lpszClassName = "SettingsClass";
  WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(Instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APP));
  
  if(RegisterClassEx(&WindowClass))
  {
    HWND Settings = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        WindowClass.lpszClassName,
        "Settings",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        0,
        Instance,
        0);
    if(Settings)
    {
      ShowWindow(Settings, SW_SHOW);
      UpdateWindow(Settings);
    }else
    {
      MessageBox(NULL, "Settings Window Creation Failed.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
      PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Failed To Register The Settings Class.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
  }

}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam)
{
 
  switch (Message){
    
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
      switch(LOWORD(WParam))
      {
        case IDM_EXIT:
        {
          PostQuitMessage(0);
        }break;
        case IDM_SETTINGS:
        {
          CreateSettings(Window);
        }break;
      }

    } break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  
  return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam); 
} 


When I press the Settings button from menu, the settings window is created. But when I close it and try to open the window again, the RegisterClassEx(&WindowClass) fails. Because of that I tried to create the settings window when the main window is create, and use ShowWindow() to open and close the settings as below:
LRESULT CALLBACK SettingsProc(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam)
{
 
  switch (Message){
    
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
      ShowWindow(Window, SW_HIDE);
    } break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  
  return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam); 
} 

void CreateSettings(HWND Window)
{
  HINSTANCE Instance =  GetModuleHandle(NULL);

  WNDCLASSEX WindowClass = {};
  WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = SettingsProc;
  WindowClass.hInstance = Instance;
  WindowClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
  WindowClass.lpszClassName = "SettingsClass";
  WindowClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(Instance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_APP));
  
  if(RegisterClassEx(&WindowClass))
  {
    HWND Settings = CreateWindowEx(
        0,
        WindowClass.lpszClassName,
        "Settings",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HWND_DESKTOP,
        0,
        Instance,
        0);
    if(Settings)
    {
      ShowWindow(Settings, SW_HIDE);
      UpdateWindow(Settings);
    }else
    {
      MessageBox(NULL, "Settings Window Creation Failed.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
      PostQuitMessage(0);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Failed To Register The Settings Class.", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    PostQuitMessage(0);
  }

}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc(HWND Window, UINT Message, WPARAM WParam, LPARAM LParam)
{
 
  switch (Message){
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
      CreateSettings(Window);
    } break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
      switch(LOWORD(WParam))
      {
        case IDM_EXIT:
        {
          PostQuitMessage(0);
        }break;
        case IDM_SETTINGS:
        {
          ShowWindow(FindWindow("SettingsClass", 0), SW_SHOW);
        }break;
      }

    } break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  
  return DefWindowProc(Window, Message, WParam, LParam); 
} 


Using this method I don't get any errors, but I don't know if it is the right way of doing it. My question is, what is the proper way of opening and closing a child window in this case?

You should be able to register the window class only once, then create the window from that class as many times as you want.

It would probably make better sense to use a DialogBox for the settings Window. There is a good overview at Dialog Box Programming Considerations.

If you want to manually replicate what (modal) dialogs do, you'll need to establish an owned window relationship. Raymond Chen has a multipart series on "Modality" on his blog that covers the topic in great depth.

@MarkRansom so Create -> Destroy is the right way to do it?
@OldBoy  how do you decide when to use a normal window or a DialogBox? Thanks for the link, I will take a look.

I didn't say that was the right way, only that you should be able to do it without error.  A dialog box is meant to pop up over its parent window and block interaction with the parent while it's up; if that's what you want, it's best to use the proper tool for the job.

It does tend to be based on what you want to do, but in general a Dialog is used to get information that is needed in order for the main window to function. That is why it is the recommended way to do it.

When you can do the job with DialogBox, use DialogBox. This is the simple rule.

You could try to use Dialog Boxes
